# iOS Photos Framework: how to revert image asset to original

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, photosframework

All the online document and samples showed how to edit/change assets with PHContentEditingInput and PHContentEditingOutput. I didn't find anything about resetting or reverting an image to its original. Anything wrote to renderedContentURL is considered an edit, so that's not what I want. Just share my findings here:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [revertAssetContentToOriginal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phassetchangerequest/1624044-revertassetcontenttooriginal)

Swift:

```
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let request = PHAssetChangeRequest(for:asset)
        request.revertAssetContentToOriginal()
    }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        if !success { print("can't revert asset: \(error)") }
    })
```

Objective C:

```
     [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
         PHAssetChangeRequest *change = [PHAssetChangeRequest changeRequestForAsset:asset];
         [change revertAssetContentToOriginal];
     } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Finished adding asset. %@", (success ? @"Success" : error));
     }];
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this, I was looking to achieve the same. You can accept your own answer after 2 days I believe.

Comment: I have noticed that `request.revertAssetContentToOriginal()` seems to have the same effect as just `request.contentEditingOutput = nil`: Revert the asset to its original state (after prompting the user for authorization). The `nil` option is more compact because it doesn't need to distinguish between both cases (it is "automatic"). However, I think I'll stick to using `revertAssetContentToOriginal()`; feels like it's the intended way (and `nil` just works by accident ), and thus less likely to break in the future...